# Trigger parent redirection after redirecting from child with emberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Assuming I have a route that contains another route:

```
this.route('fields', function () {
  this.route('details', { path: '/:field_name' });
});
```

Parent route:

```js
redirect(model, transition) {
  alert(transition.to.name);
},
```

Child route:

```js
redirect(model, transition) {
  if (something) this.transitionTo('fields');
},
```

It should alert twice when I reach the child route (since there is a redirection to the parent route). It only alerts once (before the redirection).

How can I re-trigger the parent redirect action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native class syntax:

```js
redirect() {
  if (something) super(...arguments);
}
```

Using the Ember classic class syntax:

```js
redirect() {
  if (something) this._super(...arguments);
}
```